# Why does tension on a wedge affect it at all?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I can't understand how tension is affecting the wedge in the 2nd diagram. I understand how it affects the other two masses but not how it accelerates the wedge. If the pulley is friction less wouldn't the string just slide over the pulley and not do anything?

[image: diagram of wedge with pulley on top connecting string with masses at both ends][image: previous diagram with forces vectors added in]

If you need context one of the questions I was stuck on was attempted to be answered in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaXmU6t_BKA&t=65s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the rope changes direction as it goes over the pulley, it does exert a net horizontal force on the pulley (and hence on the wedge) unless the two wedge angles are equal. This horizontal force is

$T(\cos \theta_2 - \cos \theta_1)$

However, the blocks also exert forces $R_1$ and $R_2$ on the wedge, with horizontal components $R_1 \sin \theta_1$ and $R_2 \sin \theta_2$. So the blocks exert a net horizontal force on the wedge

$R_1 \sin \theta_1  - R_2 \sin \theta_2$

If we assume there is no friction between the wedge and the ground then the total horizontal force on the wedge is

$R_1 \sin \theta_1  - R_2 \sin \theta_2 + T(\cos \theta_2 - \cos \theta_1)$

If the blocks are in equilibrium then we have $T = m_1 g \sin \theta_1$ on one side and $T = m_2 g \sin \theta_2$ on the other side. We also have $R_1 = m_1 g \cos \theta_1$ and $R_2 = m_2 g \cos \theta_2$. So the net horizontal force on the wedge is then

$m_1 g \cos \theta_1 \sin \theta_1  - m_2 g \cos \theta_2 \sin \theta_2 + T(\cos \theta_2 - \cos \theta_1)
\\ = T \cos \theta_1 - T \cos \theta_2 + T(\cos \theta_2 - \cos \theta_1)$

which is zero, as expected.

In other words, the condition for the blocks to exert zero net horizontal force on the wedge is that same as the condition for the blocks to be in equilibrium, which is $m_1 \sin \theta_1 = m_2 \sin \theta_2$.

Comment: Does that mean then when m2 goes down the slope and m1 is caught at the pulley (assuming m2 still doesn't touch the ground) the tension is forces are gone but there are still the reaction forces?

Answer (score 0):

With a massless pulley the net force on the pulley must be zero.
The three forces acting on the pulley which add up to zero are: the two tension forces and the force on the pulley due to the wedge.
Unless the two base angles are equal the force on the pulley due to the wedge is not vertical and that force has a Newton third law pair, the force on the wedge due to the pulley which again is not vertical.
As the force on the wedge due to the pulley is not vertical it will have a horizontal component which will contribute to the horizontal acceleration of the wedge.

Comment: How is there tension forces on the pulley? Wouldn't the ropes just slide around the pulley not pulling it at all?

Comment: On a frictionless surface, the center of mass will not move as masses slide around.  Think of the situation of trying to step out of a small boat onto a dock.